# RSpec/Shoulda: "should be_valid" fails, "contact.should be_valid" passes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rspec

I have the following spec:

```
  context "no firstname present" do
    let(:contact) { build :contact, firstname: 'Mickey', lastname: '', companyname: '' }
    it "should be valid" do
      should be_valid # Does not work
      contact.should be_valid # Works
    end
  end
```

Why does `should be_valid` fails, but `contact.should be_valid` passes? Within the `it` block, `should be_valid` should access `contact` anyway?! Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `subject`

```
context "no firstname present" do
  let(:contact) { build :contact, firstname: 'Mickey', lastname: '', companyname: '' }
  subject { contact }
  it { should be_valid }
end
```

#### Edit

I just discovered `its` [[link]](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.3.0/classes/Spec/Example/Subject/ExampleGroupMethods.html#M000239) which is a great way to test the `subject`'s attributes or test messages sent to it

Comment: Right, I mixed up `let()` and `subject()`. Thanks!

Comment: I completely forgot about this, thanks a lot for pointing to "its", I didn't know about this.